# Does anyone know how to remove the TextMeshPro in world icon from Play mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm writing a simple game for a school project, and a vital component is score-keeping. The TextMeshPro elements have a "preview" icon in the world space that translates to the "Play" mode. I've seen tutorials and other media where this isn't the case and would like to remove them.

I've tried to edit TMP's properties (associated script) and compared setups with my partner, who doesn't have this problem.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GizmosMenu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These should not be visible in Play mode, that's weird. If you want them not to show, you can toggle all gizmos off (top middle-right of your editor, "Gizmos"), or you can toggle each gizmo by expending this menu and activating/deactivating each)

Comment: Thanks, it was the TMP gizmo, as you suggested, but it wouldn't deactivate when toggled. 
It actually needed to be the small icon next to it that had to be toggled.